# Scope of variables and changing the global variable in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an if-else block in the function. The result depends on the value of q. If the value of q is a "well-defined query"(ex:localhost:1235/docs/q?beaven) then it should print 4. If the query is not well defined ie. q={}(ex: localhost:1235/docs), the result should have `code` and `message` as their properties(with their respective values) and passed as JSON.

But, it is not happening. I am messing up with the scope. The Output is: `""`

```
 function doSearch(app){

  return errorWrap(async function(req, res) {
    const q = req.query || {};
    try {
      // let results = await app.locals.finder.find(q);
      let results = "";
      // console.log(q);
      if(q === {}){
         results = {
          code: "BAD_PARAM",
          message: "required query parameter \"q\" is missing"
         };
         res.json(results);
      // results = await app.locals.finder.find(q);
      }else{
        results == 4;
        res.json(results);
      }

    }
    catch (err) {
      const mapped = mapError(err);
      res.status(mapped.status).json(mapped);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: try setting res.status

Answer (score 2):

`if (q === {})` will never be true because `===` tests to see if the two are the exact same object (not if they have the same properties) and that will never be the case here because `q` and `{}` are always different objects.

You probably need to test if specific properties are present on `q` or not.  Or you can test `if (Object.keys(q).length === 0)` to see if `q` is an empty object.  But, I think probably what is best for your code is to see if the specific properties you're looking for on `q` are present or not.

Comment: Your code works but it gives a warning. It says that the promise rejections that are not handled will termiante Nodejs in near future.

Comment: @Vagabond - My code suggestion has absolutely nothing to do with a rejected promise - that's elsewhere in your code and not in any code that you show in your question.  So, that appears to have nothing to do with what you've posted.  That's a separate issue that occurs in portions of your real code that you don't show here.

Comment: @Vagabond - It could also be that your `catch` block is itself throwing an error which causes `errorWrap()` to return a rejected promise which you do not handle anywhere.  That's just a wild guess possibility based on the code you have in your question.  It also could be elsewhere in your real code that a promise is rejected.